# NACL_SDK How to intercept the video stream saved as a YUV image

Tags: google-nativeclient, ppapi

nacl_sdk\pepper_44\examples\api\media_stream_video
this is a example.
i want to catch a frame to save as a YUV image.

PS.You can find some silly mistakes in my message. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

The example plugin receives frames in the OnGetFrame method and converts them to Open GL textures. Here's the code that gets the frame information:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ppapi/examples/media_stream_video/media_stream_video.cc&l=428

You would do something similar, except that instead of creating a GL texture you would save the YUV data.